# How to address in the thesis that the abstract is translated by someone

Tags: thesis, acknowledgement, abstract, translations

I have my thesis abstract translated by an Italian friend (from English to Italian). Therefore, I'm wondering if I should mention it somewhere in the abstract or acknowledgment that the Italian abstract was written by him. What is the common way in academia?

The whole thesis is in English, but I wanted to add an Italian abstract as well, since the the thesis is submitted to a university in Italy.

Comment: I'd include, in the "Acknowledgment" part of the thesis, a sentence like "I thank X for translating the abstract into Italian."  I'm not sure whether this should also be mentioned in the abstract itself.  Perhaps it would be appropriate to add, at the end of the abstract, a parenthetical sentence saying, in Italian, "Italian translation of abstract by X."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A small piece of translation like this should be clearly credited, but is not large enough that I think that it should be considered a significant piece of independent work.

As such, I think that a statement in the thesis acknowledgements would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise talking to the university you plan to submit the thesis to clarify both whether it is acceptable to include an abstract translated by another person and if-so how it should be credited.

They are the ones who get to decide what is and isn't acceptable in the thesis.